Prove using triangular inequality $\Vert a-b+d\Vert^2 - \Vert a-c+d\Vert^2 \leq 2 \Vert a-c+d\Vert\cdot\Vert b-c\Vert + \Vert b-c\Vert^2$
I came across the following statement:
Given $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}^n$, one can show using the triangular inequality that
$$\Vert a-b+d\Vert^2 - \Vert a-c+d\Vert^2 \leq 2 \Vert a-c+d\Vert\cdot\Vert b-c\Vert + \Vert b-c\Vert^2$$
holds. However, I cannot find a way to show that this statement is actually true. Can someone please help me. Thanks.

The inequality is of the form $X^2 - Y^2 \le 2YZ + Z^2$. Can you see a way to simplify it?

Take $u = a - c + d$ and $v = b - c$. The inequality is equivalent to $$||u - v||^2 - ||u||^2 \leq 2 ||u|| \cdot ||v|| + ||v||^2,$$ which is equivalent to $$||u - v||^2 \leq (||u|| + ||v||)^2,$$ which again is equivalent to $$||u - v|| \leq ||u|| + ||v||,$$ which follows from the triangle inequality, since $$||u - v|| = ||u + (-v)|| \leq ||u|| + ||-v|| = ||u|| + ||v||.$$
